# How to randomly pick numbers from ranked groups in python, to create a list of specific length

Tags: python, algorithm, random, ranking

I am trying to create a sequence of length 6 which consists of numbers randomly picked from ranked groups.
*The first element of the sequence has to be drawn from the first group, and the last element has to be drawn from the last group*.

Let the new sequence be called "seq". Then, if

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [9]
c = [5,6]
d = [11,12,4]

seq[0] in a == 1
seq[-1] in d == 1
```

The intermediate elements have to come from lists a,b,c,d. But, if the second element is randomly drawn from 'a', then the third one, has to be drawn either from a later 'a' element, or from b/c/d. Similarly, if the third element is drawn from 'c', then the other ones have to come from later ranks like d.The groups are ranked this way.

The number of groups given now, is arbitrary (maximum of 6 groups). The length for the sequence ( len(seq) == 6 ) is standard.

One element from **each** group has to be in the final sequence. Repetition of elements is not allowed. All group elements are unique (and they are always numbers in the range of 1-12).

Comment: Would there be any difference in the expected outcome (or the distribution of possible outcomes) if `b` and `c` were collapsed into a single group?

Comment: One element from every group has to be there in the final sequence. So, collapsing won't do

Comment: if I take 3 in a an 11 in d, there are only 9,5,6 for the 4 others numbers . is it a example pitfall or b or c are bigger ?

Comment: It is an example. They could be bigger or smaller. But not much larger right? the numbers are in a range from 1 to 12. So if you pick 3 from a and 11 from d, then there aren't enough numbers to fill the sequence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have four forced choices, then two free choices. `set` is a good help here.

```
from random import choice
a = [1,2,3]
b = [9]
c = [5,6]
d = [11,12,4]

l=a+b+c+d #ordered candidates

def select():
    e=set(l)
    for s in (a,b,c,d,e,e):              # 4 forced choices and 2 frees.
        e.remove(choice(tuple(s)))       # sets have no index.
    return [x for x in l if x not in e]
```

10 samples :

```
>>> for _ in range(10) : print (select())
[1, 9, 5, 11, 12, 4]
[1, 3, 9, 6, 11, 4]
[1, 3, 9, 5, 6, 12]
[1, 2, 9, 6, 11, 4]
[1, 2, 9, 5, 6, 4]
[2, 9, 5, 6, 11, 4]
[1, 2, 9, 5, 11, 12]
[1, 3, 9, 6, 11, 12]
[3, 9, 6, 11, 12, 4]
[1, 2, 9, 5, 12, 4]
```

Comment: Good job...That was a tough one and you+python delivered :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
from random import choice, randint

v = [[1, 2, 3],
      [9],
      [5, 6],
      [11, 12, 4]]


def whatever(values, n=6):
    first = [choice(values[0])]
    last = [choice(values[-1])]
    seq = []
    k = 0
    while len(seq) < n -2:
        k = randint(k, len(values)-1)
        seq.append(choice(values[k]))
    return first + seq + last

print whatever(v, 6)
```

Comment: There is repetition in the final sequence, which is not desired. 
Example answer would be: [2,9,6,11,12,4], [2,3,9,5,11,12] ....

Comment: I need clarification on the repetition issue, what happens if we reached the last list of values, and all of them are already used, but we haven't filled seq up yet?
This is an edge case I need a logic resolution from you

Comment: This is not wanted. We want an exact length of 6 for the sequence and it can't have any duplicates. There has to be a way to fill the sequence from these groups with exactly 6 numbers

Comment: You have a contradiction in flow:
"has to be drawn either from a later 'a' element, or from b/c/d" contradicts
"One element from each group has to be in the final sequence. Repetition of elements is not allowed."
If we randomly draw a list and never go back, then if I draw the second number from d[2], I can never complete the algorithm as I have reached the end of possible elements allowed to draw from.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on your last sentence, but if 'd' was larger, you could pick d[2] and still be able to fill in the rest of the sequence.

Comment: Even if d is very large, since this is a random algorithm, d[-1] can be selected for the 2nd values of seq and again we reached a dead end.
we can try different approach, enumerate all legal possible solutions, and then randomly choose from one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try z=[a,b,c,d]

Then for each element e in z, do seq.append(e[randint(0,Len(e))]), e.g.

```
from random import randint

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
z=[a,b]
print(a[randint(0,len(a))])
f=[]
for e in z:
    f.append(e[randint(0,len(e))])
print(f)
```

Or you could use a for loop instead of a for each and use a manual counter so you could have seq[counter]=...

This will not pick the groups randomly though.